# Crash when receive notification if app is closed/swipe ( React Native )

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that using Firebase push notification, when app receive notification in foreground and background, it works normally. But when I close/swipe the app it is going to be crashed.

Here is the log about the crash:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
07-16 17:16:56.218 7552-7571/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-RNFirebaseMessagingService
    Process: com.tutorial, PID: 7552
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.tutorial. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source:53)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzb(Unknown Source:191)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzc(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source:353)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:26)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
07-16 17:17:05.703 7552-7569/com.tutorial W/EnhancedIntentService: Service took too long to process intent: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE App may get closed.
```

In my app I have implement 2 method :

```
this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {

                senName = notification.data.senderName;
                senUid = notification.data.senderUid;

                const showNotif = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
                    .setNotificationId('notificationId')
                    .setTitle(notification.title)
                    .setBody(notification.data.text)
                    .android.setChannelId('channel_id_foreground')
                    .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher');
                firebase.notifications().displayNotification(showNotif)

            });
```

and

```
    this.notificationOpenListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
        // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
        const action = notificationOpen.action;
        // Get information about the notification that was opened
        const notification = notificationOpen.notification;

        if (!senName || !senUid) {
            senName = notification.data.senderName;
            senUid = notification.data.senderUid;
        }

        var roomUid = this.generateChatId(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, senUid);
        this.goToChatRoomWithId('ChatScreen', senName, senUid, roomUid);
    });
```

Anybody know this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `react-native-firebase` lib.

**Library info**:

Introduction
RNFirebase makes using Firebase with React Native simple. It is a light-weight layer sitting on-top of the native Firebase libraries for both iOS and Android which mirrors the Firebase Web SDK as closely as possible.

***Although the Firebase Web SDK library will work with React Native, it is mainly built for the web.***

RNFirebase provides a JavaScript bridge to the native Firebase SDKs for both iOS and Android therefore Firebase will run on the native thread, allowing the rest of your app to run on the JS thread. The Firebase Web SDK also runs on the JS thread, therefore potentially affecting the frame rate causing jank with animations, touch events etc.

The native SDKs also allow us to hook into device sdk's which are not possible with the web SDK, for example crash reporting, offline realtime database support, analytics and more!

All in all, RNFirebase provides much faster performance (~2x) over the web SDK and provides device sdk's not found in the web sdk (see the feature table below).

**My recommended :** [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)

Comment: Thanks for your useful advise, finally I have solved this problem. Just make a little change:              
**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'** 
to                 
**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'**

Comment: `react-native-fcm` recommends using `react-native-firebase`